# AWS Elastic Load Balancer - Force healthcheck reload

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

When my servers are under planned maintenance ELB healthcheck fails and it takes all servers out of service.

Is there a way to tell ELB to recheck the healtcheck URL? So far I found that changing one of the properties (such as "Health Check Interval") reloads the checks, but is there a command/a proper way to achieve that?

Comment: I assume you mean ELB and not EBS.  What are the Interval and threshold values that you have defined in the ELB?

Comment: Yes, thanks, edited. The values are the defaults. But the values don't matter - I just want to re-run the checks for all nodes.

Comment: The checks will re-run automatically at the next defined Interval, which if it's the default is 30 seconds. What's wrong with waiting a maximum of 30 seconds for the checks to be re-run?  It seems like an awful lot of effort for virtually no gain.

Comment: Problem was that "Healthy Threshold" default was 10, which would take 300 seconds to recover. Changed it to 2 and lowered the interval to 15. But sometimes you want it active *right now*, so a script should do.

Answer (score 2):

Detach and reattach the instances to the ELB

Comment: I might as well change the single Interval property which will trigger the healthcheck ping for all instances. I guess there's no other way...